# selectbox fire event when value is not changed. Listener not allowed

Tags: android, jquery, html, windows-phone-8, jquery-events

We all know jQuerys `.change()` event handler .

However it only fires if the value of the selectbox has been changed. Is there an event that fires also if I pick the same value I already have now?.

```
<select>
 <option value="a" selected="selected">A</option>
 <option value="b">B</option>
</select
```

If I now choose the selectbox and choose A, which event can be fired?

Background: I cant use a click listener, because I need to fire `.blur()` on the selectbox, to prevent blue highlight color of the select box on `windows phone 8`.

However, on a Samsung Galaxy S3, the `.blur()` prevents `android` native select drop down menu to pop up, because it gets immediatly unfocused (it´s what `.blur()` does) after clicking the select box when using a `.click()` or a `.focus()` listener.

Comment: can you describe why you need to handle a non-state-changing event ?

Answer (score 0):

You could force a change event by calling

```
$('select').trigger('change');
```

Comment: is there a way to only fire this when the currently selected value is choosen?